# send message from Twilio Production environment

Tags: twilio

Recently I have integrated Twillio to send WhatsApp. And as of now we are joining the sandbox and adding the user to send the message.

How will this work in the production environment?

I want to send the message from the production environment without scanning the QR code.

Comment: Please take a [tour] and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp allows you to get started building and prototyping your applications immediately without needing to register your WhatsApp Senders and Facebook Business Manager information first.

For production usage, you need (1) a Twilio phone number and (2) a Meta Business Manager account. With this, you can get started straight away from the console using our Self Sign-Up process. Find out more about [Self Sign-Up here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up).

Then, your customers can immediately message this phone number and won't need to scan the code. Further, you are able to initiate conversations with pre-approved messaging templates.

[More details](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007721954-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-for-WhatsApp)